# Outlook Email Archiving Macro Doesnt work if subject has asterisk

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using the following code to archive my emails to a designated folder which works perfectly at the moment.... UNLESS the email subject contains an *... this then gives a debug message "run-time error '-2147286788 (800300fc)'

Is there anything I can add into the below code to make it ignore or replace the * to something else to allow it to automatically archive these emails?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Received2016()

Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim objItem As Object

Dim sPath As String

Dim dtDate As Date

Dim sName As String

Dim enviro As String

enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection

Set oMail = objItem

sName = oMail.Subject

ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime

sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyy-mm-dd - ", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _

vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "hh-nn-ss", _

vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & " - " & sName & ".msg"

sPath = "H:\Email Archive\2016 Emails\Received\"

Debug.Print sPath & sName

oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olMSG

Next

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _

sChr As String _

)

sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)

sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)

sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)

sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)

sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)

sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)

sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)

sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)

End Sub
```

Comment: add * to your replace function.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the Replaces and add in this instead (changing characters as necessary) -

```
sName = RemoveSpecials(sName)

Function RemoveSpecials(strInput As String) As String
    Dim strChars As String
    strChars = "!£$%^&*()_+{}@~:<>?,./;'#[]-=`¬¦" & Chr(34)
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    For intIndex = 1 To Len(strChars)
        strInput = Replace(strInput, Mid(strChars, intIndex, 1), "")
    Next
    RemoveSpecials = strInput
End Function
```