# How to SaveAs with Subject in file name?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to save to hard drive all the mails in my Outlook folders.

```vb
'==========================================
' Save Inbox Mail Items To The File System
'==========================================
Sub saveInboxMailItemsToFileSystem()
    ' Set variables
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String
    ' Set namespace
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    ' Get inbox folder
    Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    ' Loop through all mail items
    For Each item In inbox.Items
        ' Set filename
        strFileName = "C:\Users\<moi>\SvgMail\" & VBA.Format(item.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) & " - " & item.Subject & ".msg"
        ' Save mail item to file system
        item.SaveAs strFileName, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG
    Next item
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

> Erreur d'exécution '-2147286788 (800300fc)': Echec de l'opération.

Comment: Is this a typo `<moi>` in the file name? The chars `< >` are not allowed.

Comment: No is just a replacement string for my username <me> but obviously in real life it does not contain "<" nor ">"

Comment: Make sure the email subject doesn't contain any illegal characters.

Comment: The error is `STG_E_INVALIDNAME`, which means the COM system cannot create the OLE storage (MSG) file. See Eugene's reply.

Comment: I would add in an error check to ensure `TypeName(item) = "MailItem"` before attempting to save the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the result file name (`strFileName`) is valid and contains only allowed symbols. Try to save any file using the problematic name and you will be notified that some symbols are not allowed. But in our case the Outlook object model doesn't give you meaningful answers, it just notifies you about a problem. You, as a developer, should analyze such cases and fix the problem. For example, if you try to search for the error code you may find a similar thread - [Outlook Email Archiving Macro Doesnt work if subject has asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474383/outlook-email-archiving-macro-doesnt-work-if-subject-has-asterisk). For example, you may find a sample function which replaces some characters for using in the `SaveAs` call:

```
Function FixFileName(FileName As String) As String
Dim fname As String


fname = Trim(FileName)


fname = Replace(fname, " ", "_")
fname = Replace(fname, ",", "")
fname = Replace(fname, "'", "")
fname = Replace(fname, "(", "")
fname = Replace(fname, ")", "")
fname = Replace(fname, "~", "")
fname = Replace(fname, "*", "")
fname = Replace(fname, "?", "")
fname = Replace(fname, "/", "")
fname = Replace(fname, "\", "")
fname = Replace(fname, """", "")


FixFileName = fname


End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. In complement I've found the related MS doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file